# Присвоение значений js

Tags: javascript

> В рабочей области вы найдете объявленный объект, называемый home. Объект обладает свойствами: name, street, city, state, zipcode. Ваша задача объявить переменную fullAddress и присвоить ей значение типа String, содержащее полный адрес, используя информацию с объекта home, но не копируя значение свойств, а ссылаясь на них.
>
> Финальный вид полного адреса: 8, Kuznetsky str., Moskva, Russia, 101000
>
> Проверяются все переменные на корректность присвоенных значений, поэтому ничего не изменяйте в объекте home.
>
> ```
> const home = {
>     name: 'Svetlana Sikora',
>     street: '8, Kuznetsky',
>     city: 'Moskva.',
>     state: 'Russia',
>     zipcode: '101000'
> }
> const fullAddress = {...home}
> ```

Comment: `используя информацию с объекта home, но не копируя значение свойств` это как нужно понимать?

Comment: Ссылаться на них с помощью rest parameters или spread

Comment: Какое отношение rest/spread имеет к «копрированию значений»?

Comment: Оно ссылаеться на значения и их можно изменять. Я так понимаю. Я сейчас только учусь, может я не так понимаю. Есть задание, его нужно как-то сделать.

Comment: Я бы начал с моего первого вопроса автору задачи

Answer (score 0):

??

```
const fullAddress = `${[...Object.values(home).slice(1, Object.values(home).length)]}`
```

UPD:

```
const fullAddress = [...Object.values(home).slice(1, Object.values(home).length)].join(', ')
```

Comment: Почти верно, все значение должны быть отдельно. Получается так: ``8, Kuznetsky,Moskva,Russia,101000``, а должно так: ``8, Kuznetsky str., Moskva, Russia, 101000``. Должно быть с пробелами. Спасибо большое за помощь.

Comment: @lilbodyn Исправил

Comment: О точно, как я сам не додумался. Еще нужно к улице добавить в конце str.))) Спасибо тебе большое за помощь)))